# Problemas con arreglo de objetos

Tags: javascript, array, funciones, objeto

tenbgo crear una función llamada `arregloDeObjetos` que reciba un número y una palabra como parámetro y devuelva un arreglo de objetos que tenga: una propiedad llamada como la palabra pasada por parámetro y el valor del número y sus anteriores. EJEMPLO:

```
arregloDeObjetos(5, “hola”) debe retornar [{hola: 1}, {hola: 2}, {hola: 3}, {hola: 4}, {hola: 5 }]
```

Esto es lo que tengo hecho

```
        function arregloDeObjetos(num, palabra) {
    let res = [];
    for(let i = 0; i <= num; i++){
    res.push({});
  }
    return res;
  ;
```

El problema es que en res.push({}) no me deja poner dos variables, osea quiero poner la variable palabra como propiedad pero no me deja, me la toma como string

Answer (score 0):

Siempre lo he hecho de la forma: `{[palabra]:i}`, no sabria explicarlo ahora mismo, pero eso te funcionara.

```js
function arregloDeObjetos(num, palabra) {
    let res = [];
    for(let i = 1; i <= num; i++){
    res.push({[palabra]:i});
  }
    return res;
}
console.log(arregloDeObjetos(5,"hola"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Para este ejemplo te aconsejo crear un objeto en cada iteración, para que entiendas cómo se crean, para ello puedes ayudarte utilizando un [iniciador de objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos#Object_initializers). Pero obviamente, puedes hacerlo directamente tal y como lo hiciste en tu pregunta.

```
function arregloDeObjetos(num, name)
{
    let arr = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < num; i++){
        let objeto = {
             [name] : i + 1
        };

        arr.push(objeto);   
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Gracias a que ECS6 define [`ComputedPropertyName`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-evaluation), puedes acceder al valor de `name` usando los brackets `[]`. Dado que el mismo nombre lo dice `computed`, también puedes hacer concatenaciones u otras operaciones dentro de los brackes, tal como:

```
[name + "123"]
[1 + 2 + 3]
```